# How to make doc.id clickable item?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, processing

How can I turn doc.id into clickable item?
Right now I can get data from my database, I can list all the doc.id's, but I want to make those into hyperlinks, when pressed it gets the data from the database and shows it's data as a drawing on the canvas. If that makes sense?

doc.id is that unique id for stuff that is saved in my firestore db.

```
const allDrawings = document.querySelector('#allDrawings');

function renderDrawings(doc){
    let li = document.createElement('li');
    let key = document.createElement('doc.id');

    li.setAttribute('data-id', doc.id);
    key.textContent = doc.id;

    li.appendChild(key);

    allDrawings.appendChild(li);

}

db.collection('joonistused').get().then((snapshot) => {
    snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
        renderDrawings(doc);
        console.log(doc.id);
    })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're just trying to create an anchor in the DOM then try something like this:

```
const anchor = document.createElement('a');
anchor.href = `/some/path/to/${doc.id}`;
anchor.innerText = `Document ID ${doc.id}`;

// <a href="/some/path/to/123">Document ID 123</a>
```

Comment: What is the URL supposed to look like? Can you share an example?

Comment: I mean, I want every doc.id be a clickable, like hyperlink?

Comment: I get that. I was just wondering what the format of the URL is; like `http://whatever.com/docs/id` or something similar. My example shows how to create clickable links you just need to edit the `href` with the format of your URL and the `innerText` with the ID if that's all you want to display.

Comment: example: http://puu.sh/EAPXM/f70a13062f.png See how its blue just like that and I can click on that? I want all those be like that and the path is their name, basically the path is just their URL link, but how can I path it to it self? if it makes sense? this is what is confusing

Comment: Yes, understand fully that you want a clickable link. If you look at my example where  you see `anchor.href =` this is where you define the URL. My example shows a made up path `/some/path/to/${doc.id}` but yours may be `https://mywebsite.com/docs/${doc.id}`. So you can edit that line to put however your URL is structured.

Comment: I think what the OP is asking for is not so much to have a URL that is the target of a link but instead have a "clickable" that, when clicked, will dynamically retrieve a record from the Firestore database and then display that retrieved record/document.

Comment: Hmm okay, thats one way but I don't think I can use it the way I need it.. 
Okay.. I am using p5.js and firestore(firebase), I want to make a canvas where people can draw, then hit the save button to save the drawing, and then under the canvas, you can see saved drawings. When you click on the link then it uses `"showDrawing(){ var key = this.html();}"` something like that. So the links URL must be the doc.id itself. Everytime you refresh the website then you can see the list of saved drawings linking to its saved drawing in the database. So confusing, I know, can't find any help on google.

Comment: I have been trying different things for hours now, I can't seem to find anything that works like that, I know its possible in the older versions.. but I can't find any workaround. This is why I am asking help, I feel like my head is exploding. I am probably missing something. I can show the rest of the other codes if needed. I appreciate all the help I can get! <3 @Kolban yes, something like that!

Comment: So do you want to make a call to Firebase when the link is clicked to load a new drawing?

Comment: I guess thats a way of saying it, yes. My goal is to get it work like that yes, when I click on that link then it loads the saved path/mouseX/Y on the canvas and you can see the savings. But that should come with showDrawing() and oneDrawing() but I can't get the current doc.id's to hyperlinks, if it makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is a design/logic to list documents in a firestore collection in your browser and make them list items.  You then want to click on an item and have the content for that document displayed to the user.  This will require programming logic on your end.  You will want to write browser/client side JavaScript that is called when a link is clicked (onclick).  When the JavaScript code is reached you will then want to make a web client call to the Firestore database to retrieve the corresponding document.

See: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference.html#get

This looks very useful too:

[Firebase Firestore Tutorial #3 - Getting Documents](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kmTECF0JZyQ)

Comment: This comment extends the comments for the other answer ... I'm sensing that you are writing data into the database.  This is internal data (not HTML).  I am then sensing that you want to have a link that, when clicked, retrieves that data and ... from the data ... presents it in some fashion.  Is this correct?  If so, then it is likely that you don't actually mean a "URL Link" which is commonly an anchor tag that, when clicked, causes the browser to load a different page.  I suspect that when you say link, you really mean a clickable item (question).